# Is there a way to clear the console in python like there is in c#?

Tags: python, c#, console

In c# I can simply clear the console with Console.Clear();. Is there a way to simply clear the console in python like there is in c#?

Comment: For future questions, please do some research before hand as repetitive questions are quite common. So in an attempt, I'm writing this to make one less user prone to repeat the same mistake many others do. Searching online for simple keywords like "python clear console" gives more than plenty results, one of which is the link above. Voting to close this as it's duplicated many times, and I leave you Nicholas with the note that when asking questions, we'd like to see some effort in trying to solve things on your own before asking us for help, as we're not a coding service. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use os like this:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```